# Is there a way to remove the manifest.json request from react build

Tags: reactjs

As stated, I want to exclude the creation and request for manifest.json when I run react-script build. The reason is because I am getting errors relating to cors when trying to get it.

Since I run the build and deploy on a pipeline I cant manually go in and edit the index.html after it builds.

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem.  Instead of trying to solve your *actual* problem (CORS) you are trying to "go around" the problem.  It should be possible to do what you are asking, but it's likely that if you have CORS issues with `manifest.json`, you could have CORS issues with other files in the future.

Comment: I tried to address the CORS issue but I can't figure it out. The rest of the app works fine